# How to use seasonal_decompose from statsmodels with PySpark DF / How to Convert DataFrame to Time Series Array

Tags: machine-learning, pyspark, time-series, databricks, statsmodels

I have a spark Dataframe with two columns (time_key with dates 7 days in between them and qty), just like this:

| time_key | qty |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-10-26 | 10 |
| 2023-10-19 | 12 |
| 2023-10-12 | 14 |

I am trying to use the function"seasonal_decompose" from the library "statsmodels" with PySpark. I know how to use in Pandas, I can transform the time_key column in the index and the function "seasonal_decompose" works just fine. But I am trying to use it in PySpark. I think I have one option (I am saying this because of the documentation of the function: https://shorturl.at/ovC35): convert the DF to a array_like time series?

I tried the following approaches:

1. I converted the time_key column to a date type (with the function "to_date", initially the column was string type). Then I tried to create an array like this:

```
time_series_array = [(row.time_key, row.qty_total) for row in df_iter.collect()]
```

and I got this:

```
[(datetime.date(2020, 11, 1), 0.0), (datetime.date(2020, 8, 30), 0.0), ... ]
```

And then I applied the function:

```
seasonal_decompose(time_series_array)
```

but then I got this error:

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.date'
```

And I was like "ok, so maybe the problem was converting to a data type, let me keep it as a string then".

2. Keeping it as a string, and the array I got was something like this:

   [('2020-11-01', 0.0), ('2020-08-30', 0.0), ...]

but then I got this error after applying the array to the function:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2020-11-01'
```

How can i fix this? How can I transform my original DF to use the function "seasonal_decompose"? Or how can I convert my original DF to an time series array? Is there a function in PySpark that does the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a following working example of how to use statsmodels.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def print_pandas(dataframe_given):
    with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None,'display.max_columns', None, 'expand_frame_repr', False):
        print("Given pandas dataframe name")
        print(dataframe_given)


np.random.seed(42)
time = np.arange(122)
trend = time * 0.1
seasonal = 5 * np.sin(time * 2 * np.pi / 12)
residual = np.random.randn(time.shape[0]) * 2
data = trend + seasonal + residual
date_rng = pd.date_range(start='2020-01-01', end='2020-05-01', freq='D')
ts = pd.Series(data, date_rng)

print_pandas(ts)

result = seasonal_decompose(ts, model='additive')

result.plot()
plt.show()
```

Output of the plot as an image :

[image]